# Exitence of a root for a function

Tags: roots

I want to prove that $f(\psi)$ defined below, has at least one root. I tried using intermediate value theorem but I could not prove the existence of a root. I would appreciate it if anybody could help.

$f(\psi)=\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{\alpha_i sin(\psi+\theta_i)}{2+cos(\psi-\theta_i)}$

$\alpha_i$ and $\theta_i$ are given for every $i$ and we have

$\forall i \in \{1,2,...,K\} : 0 \leq \alpha_i \leq 1$  and $-\pi \leq \theta_i \leq \pi$.

Comment: What trouble did you have with the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Well to use that theorem, you need to find two points say $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ for which $f(\psi_1) \times f(\psi_2)<0$. I could not find those two points.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $f$ has no roots. "It can be shown" that $f$ is continuous (critically, the denominator is never equal to $0$), so $f$ is therefore everywhere greater (or less) than $0$. Without loss of generality, assume

$$\forall \psi\ f(\psi) > 0$$

Therefore, the integral of $f$ with respect to $\psi$ is always greater than $0$, and moreover, always increasing. Considering just the interval $[0,2\pi]$, then, we have

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\psi)\ d\psi \neq 0$$

Since $f$ is a sum, its integral is equal to the sum of its summands' integrals on the same interval.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{i} f_i(\psi)\ d\psi = \sum_{i} \int_{0}^{2\pi}f_i(\psi)\ d\psi$$

Each of these summands $f_i$ is a periodic function centered at $0$:

$$f_i(\psi)=\frac{\alpha_i sin(\psi+\theta_i)}{2+cos(\psi-\theta_i)}$$

"It can be shown" that over the period of $2\pi$ each $f_i$ spends equal amounts of time above and below $0$. That is,

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f_i(\psi)\ d\psi = 0$$

$$\therefore \sum_{i} \int_{0}^{2\pi}f_i(\psi)\ d\psi = 0$$

$$\therefore \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\psi)\ d\psi = 0$$

But this is a contradiction: this integral is supposed to be positive. Therefore, our initial assumption is false: $f$ must have a root.

Comment: Nice approach! The only problem is I don't understand why $\int_0^{2\pi} f_i(\psi) d\psi=0$. Would you please prove that as well?

Comment: Ah, that's not true in general, is it? When  $\theta_i = -\frac{\pi}{4}$, for example, the integral of $f_i$ isn't periodic: http://imgur.com/a/o8sCp.

Comment: I guess not. I also tried some numbers and the integral was not zero.

Comment: if it was $cos(\psi+\theta_i)$ in the denominator, then the integral was zero. I liked your approach though. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's a long comment and because of this I write it here. If $0 \leq \theta_i \leq \pi$ then $0\leq\sin(\theta_i)\leq 1$ and because of $2+\cos(\theta_i)>0$ and $2-\cos(\theta_i)>0$, we have:

\begin{align}
0\leq f(0)=\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{\alpha_i sin(\theta_i)}{2+cos(\theta_i)}
< \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i sin(\theta_i)< K\\
\\
0\geq f(\pi)=\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{-\alpha_i sin(\theta_i)}{2-cos(\theta_i)}
> \sum_{i=1}^K -\alpha_i sin(\theta_i)>  -K
\end{align}
then there is a $\psi\in [0,\pi]$, such that $f(\psi)=0$.

If $-\pi \leq \theta_i \leq 0$ then $-1\leq\sin(\theta_i)\leq 0$ and because of $2+\cos(\theta_i)>0$ and $2-\cos(\theta_i)>0$, we have:

\begin{align}
0\geq f(0)=\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{\alpha_i sin(\theta_i)}{2+cos(\theta_i)}
> \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i sin(\theta_i)> -K\\
\\
0\leq f(-\pi)=\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{-\alpha_i sin(\theta_i)}{2-cos(\theta_i)}
< \sum_{i=1}^K -\alpha_i sin(\theta_i)<  K
\end{align}
then there is a $\psi\in [-\pi,0]$, such that $f(\psi)=0$.

Now, if $-\pi \leq \theta_i \leq \pi$, then we can rearrange the function $f(\psi)$  as follows: 
$$f(\psi)=g(\psi)+h(\psi)$$
 such that $0 \leq \theta_i(g(\psi)) \leq \pi$ and $-\pi \leq \theta_i(h(\psi)) \leq 0$. Therefore, 
there is a $\psi_1\in [0,\pi]$ where $g(\psi_1)=0$ and there is a $\psi_2\in [-\pi,0]$ where $h(\psi_2)=0$.

*My conjecture:* There is a $\psi_3\in [\psi_2,\psi_1]$ such that $f(\psi_3)=0$.

I hope it be useful.